# Finite fields are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, field-theory

This is from *A Course in Arithmetic* by JP Serre

> > Theorem 1
> >
> > ii) Let $p$ be a prime number and let $q = p^f(f \geq 1)$ be a power of $p$. Let
> >      be an algebraically closed field $\Omega$ of characteristic $p$. There exists a  unique subfield $F_q$ of $\Omega$ which has $q$ elements. It is the set of roots of the polynomial$X^q-X$.
> >
> > iii) All finite fields with $p^f$ elements are isomorphic to $F_q$.

The proof of the last part says

> > Assertion iii) follows from ii) and from the fact that all fields with $p^f$
> >     elements can be embedded in $\Omega$, since $\Omega$ is algebraically closed.

Can someone explain me how iii) follows fom ii)?

Comment: If we had two fields $L,K$ which have cardinality $p^f$, then both are algebraic over $\mathbb{F}_p$, and so they both embed into $\overline{\mathbb{F}_p}$, but by (ii) they have the same image, and in particular are both isomorphic to that image and thus to each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $E$ be a field with $q$ elements. By (iii), it is isomorphic to a subfield of $\Omega$. By (ii), there's only one such subfield, namely $F_q$.

Comment: You are using what you want to prove.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a little Galois Theory: by (ii) *any* field $\,\Bbb F_q\,$ is *the* splitting field of $\,x^q-x\,$ over $\,\Bbb F_p\,$ , and "the" comes from the uniqueness, up to isomorphism, of the splitting field...